# How to make a div keep a same place when scrolling web page. (floating DIV)

Tags: jquery

i have make a div to keep a same place of the web page when it is scrolling. but it dose not work.

$(function(){

```
    var offsetPixels = 720;
    $(window).scroll(function (){
       if($(window).scrollTop()>offsetPixels)
       {
           $('.fixeddv').css({
              'possition':'fixed',
              'top':'50px'
           });
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6f2dqd0g/3/) to demonstrate how you can achive what you want.

JS looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fixed').css({
              'position':'fixed',
              'top':'50px',
              'border': '2px solid red'
           });
});
```

You also had a typo in: "possition" it's written like so: "position".

Comment: one problem! its working, but when reducing the window width, floating DIV is hiding by the right edge of the window.

Comment: @HarshaPriyalal i guess we are talking about responsibilty of the site? Here is an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRZqSKp71mI

Comment: yes, But i developed not a Website it is a web based software, so i do not need to make it as a responsive. if just anyone reduce the size of the window, the DIV is not appear properly. because of that, i need to keep it be response the size of the window.

Comment: @HarshaPriyalal I think you need something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/CG9WN/829/ Hope that example can help you.